# How to perform an action in Android when receiving and SMS?

Tags: android, sms

Can someone please help me figure out how to perform an action when sms is received, is there a special method for it? Will it automatically be ran in the background? The only thing I know is that I need to use permission RECEIVE_SMS.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentFilter`.  Check them out in the SDK reference.

If you register an `IntentFilter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with your registration of the `BroadcastReceiver` then it will be picked by your `BroadcastReceiver` in the background.  Look at `Intent` and the actions provided.