# How to invoke an activity on SMS receive in Android?

Tags: java, android, sms

My application is receiving an SMS and I want to invoke an activity on receiving that SMS. How do I do this?

Comment: wrongly tagged. how come it `javascript` ?? ,retagging

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998175/how-to-perform-an-action-in-android-when-receive-sms

Comment: @krookedking - related but somewhat different. Here we want to invoke an activity (which ..., sure, yes, ... can be the "payload" of an action - but at least he needs some sort of service in the background in addition to the application/activity)

Answer (score 0):

create receiver like this

```
     <receiver android:name=".BroadcastServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

in class do whatever you want

```
public class BroadcastServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        // do you want   
      }    
}
```